# Can't get rb-fsevent gem working on OSX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard, listen, fsevents

I was running Test::Unit with Guard and am trying to switch over to RSpec.

I'm running Mac OSX and can't seem to get rb-fsevent working.  When I start Guard I get a message "[Listen warning]: Listen will be polling changes. Learn more at https://github.com/guard/listen#polling-fallback."

I have tried various approaches:

- "gem install rb-fsevent" (as per [railscast 275](http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test?view=asciicast))
- Adding rb-fsevent to my Gemfile (see below)
- Specifying a rb-fsevent version (e.g. 0.9.1)
- Re-starting Guard, Rails & the whole system

Gemfile (as recommended in [Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/)):

```
    group :development, :test do
      gem "rspec-rails"
      gem "guard-rspec"
    end

    group :test do
      gem 'rb-fsevent'
    end
```

**Edit:**

I also tried including rb-fsevent to the development group (recommended in [Railscast 264](http://railscasts.com/episodes/264-guard)):

```
    group :development, :test do
      gem "rspec-rails"
      gem "guard-rspec"
      gem 'rb-fsevent'
    end
```

However I got the same error.  One clue may be that if I run guard without bundle exec then I get "Guard here! It looks like your project has a Gemfile, yet you are running `guard` outside of Bundler."  bundle exec doesn't seem to be necessary in the tutorials.

Any ideas on what might be going wrong, or how I could get more information on the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've the same problem starting with Listen 0.5.0 and an [issue](https://github.com/guard/listen/issues/60) has already been reported. Until it's resolved, you can simply use the previous version of Listen by adding:

`gem 'listen', '0.4.7'`

to your `Gemfile` and run `bundle update`.

Answer (score 0):

move `gem 'rb-fsevent'` inside `group :development, :test` block

(because guard is running in development env)

Comment: Thanks sumskyi.  I also tried this but got the same error message. I updated the question to reflect this.